# I'm not implementing `Collections.rotate` right?

Tags: java, collections

Assume I have an object of type `FixedPlan` called `fixedPlan`.

A `FixedPlan` object contains:

- a `List` of `FixedSubPlan` objects called `listOfSubPlans`
- a `HashMap<String, List<Plant>>` called `listOfFamilies` with `String` keys (they're names for plant families) and a `List` of `Plant` objects as values. In fact, I made this a `LinkedHashMap`.

A `FixedSubPlan` object contains:

- A `List<String>` called `orderOfFamilies` of plant families. These represent the order of each family in a `FixedSubPlan`.

A `Plant` object containts:

- Several attributes relating to plant characteristics

When I add a `Plant` called `newPlant` to my `FixedPlan`, I have to check whether the family of `newPlant` exists, and if it does, simply add it to my `LinkedHashMap` under the existing key or family, like: `fixedPlan.get("OldFamily").add(newPlant);`. If it doesn't, I have to put up a new key or family in my `HashMap` and add `newPlant` to a temporary list so I can insert it in my `HashMap`, like so: `listOfFamilies.put("NewFamily", tempList);`. **BUT** the number of `FixedSubPlan` items in `listOfSubPlans` should equal to the number of keys in `listOfFamilies`. Thus, for every family added, there's a new `FixedSubPlan` object. And even more, I had to arrange the each `FixedSubPlan` object's `orderOfFamilies` in such a way that, if I had 3 families:

- FixedSubPlan 1: Family A, Family B, Family C
- FixedSubPlan 2: Family B, Family C, Family A
- FixedSubPlan 3: Family C, Family A, Family B

And if I remove a family, I have to remove also the last `FixedSubPlan` in the list, like, from the example above, if I remove *Family B*, my `listOfSubPlans` should be as follows:

- FixedSubPlan 1: Family A, Family C
- FixedSubPlan 2: Family C, Family A

I already have the following code:

For FixedPlan:

```
public class FixedPlan {

String name; // Name of plan
HashMap<String, List<Plant>> listOfFamilies; // HashMap containing Plant Family Names as keys and a List of plants
List<FixedSubPlan> listOfSubPlans;

public FixedPlan() {
    name = null;
    listOfFamilies = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    listOfSubPlans = new ArrayList<>();
}

public FixedPlan(String name, HashMap<String, List<Plant>> listOfFamilies, List<FixedSubPlan> listOfSubPlans) {
    this.name = name;
    this.listOfFamilies = (LinkedHashMap) listOfFamilies;
    this.listOfSubPlans = listOfSubPlans;
}

public List<String> getFamilyNames() {
    List<String> listOfFamilies = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String key : this.listOfFamilies.keySet()) {
        listOfFamilies.add(key);
    }
    return listOfFamilies;
}

public int getNumberOfSubPlans() {
    return listOfSubPlans.size();
}

public void addPlant(Plant newPlant) {
    String family = newPlant.getFamilyName();
    if (listOfFamilies.containsKey(family)) {
        listOfFamilies.get(family).add(newPlant);
    }
    else {
        List<Plant> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        tempList.add(newPlant);
        addFamily(family, tempList);
    }
}

public void addFamily(String newFamily, List<Plant> newPlants) {
    if (getNumberOfFamilies() == 0) {
        listOfFamilies.put(newFamily, newPlants);
        listOfSubPlans.add(new FixedSubPlan(getNumberOfSubPlans(), getFamilyNames()));
        return;
    }

    String lastFamily = getFamilyNames().get(getNumberOfFamilies() - 1);
    listOfFamilies.put(newFamily, newPlants);
    for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfSubPlans(); i++) {
        listOfSubPlans.get(i).addFamily(lastFamily, newFamily);
    }

    FixedSubPlan newSubPlan = new FixedSubPlan(getNumberOfSubPlans(), getFamilyNames());
    newSubPlan.rotateFamily(getNumberOfSubPlans());
    listOfSubPlans.add(newSubPlan);
}

public void removePlant(Plant plant) {
    if (isPlantPresent(plant)) {
        String familyOfPlant = plant.getFamilyName();
        // remove plant from the ArrayList
        listOfFamilies.get(familyOfPlant).remove(plant);
        // if the number of plants under the key "familyOfPlant" equals to 0; there's no use keeping it;
        // thus, delete
        if (listOfFamilies.get(familyOfPlant).size() == 0)
            removeFamily(familyOfPlant);
    }
}

public void removeFamily(String family) {
    if (isFamilyPresent(family)) {
        listOfFamilies.remove(family);
        for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfSubPlans(); i++) {
            listOfSubPlans.get(i).removeFamily(family);
        }
        listOfSubPlans.remove(getNumberOfSubPlans() - 1);
    }
}
```

For `FixedSubPlan`:

```
public class FixedSubPlan implements Parcelable {

int year;
List<String> orderOfFamilies;

public FixedSubPlan(int year, List<String> orderOfFamilies) {
    this.year = year;
    this.orderOfFamilies = orderOfFamilies;
}

public List<String> getOrderOfFamilies() {
        return orderOfFamilies;
    }

public void addFamily(String lastFamily, String newFamily) {
    int indexOfLastFamily = orderOfFamilies.indexOf(lastFamily);
    orderOfFamilies.add(indexOfLastFamily + 1, newFamily);
}

public void removeFamily(String family) {
    orderOfFamilies.remove(family);
}

public void rotateFamily(int distance) {
    Collections.rotate(orderOfFamilies, distance);
}
```

I think my `remove` function works well. I guess. But I'm having troubles with my `addFamily()` method. For example, I added 4 `Plant` objects from 4 different families; I'll get:

- SubPlan 1: Family A, Family B, Family C
- SubPlan 2: Family B, Family C, Family A
- SubPlan 3: Family B, Family C, Family A
- SubPlan 4: Family B, Family C, Family A

Only the first two `SubPlans` are correct. :/ Actually, NO. I want the items to go an index down. But I'm getting this. They're going an index up.

So, to summarize, I'm assuming the problem arises in this piece of code:

```
FixedSubPlan newSubPlan = new FixedSubPlan(getNumberOfSubPlans(), getFamilyNames());
newSubPlan.rotateFamily(getNumberOfSubPlans());
listOfSubPlans.add(newSubPlan);
```

It's in the method `addFamily()`. Also, I didn't post my entire code. That's just too lengthy. I might place it in here instead if requested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much backtracking, I've finally solved my problem. I needed to replace my code with this:

```
FixedSubPlan newSubPlan = new FixedSubPlan(getNumberOfSubPlans(), getFamilyNames());
newSubPlan.rotateFamily(getNumberOfSubPlans() * -1);
listOfSubPlans.add(newSubPlan);
```

It's a little tricky to explain. But the way I insert new families (as seen below), is the reason.

```
for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfSubPlans(); i++) {
    listOfSubPlans.get(i).addFamily(lastFamily, newFamily);
}
```